# Get Year of parameter dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a way for me to get the year of the months based on the parameter given?

```
DECLARE @StartDate  DATETIME,
        @EndDate    DATETIME;

SELECT   
    @StartDate = '2016-02-01',
    @EndDate   = '2017-03-01';

SELECT  
    /*is there a way for me to get the year of months based on the parameter dates*/
    /*DATEPART(YEAR, DATEADD(YEAR, x.number, @StartDate)) AS Year,*/ 
    DATEPART(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, x.number, @StartDate)) AS Month,
    DATENAME(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, x.number, @StartDate)) AS MonthName
FROM    
    master.dbo.spt_values x
WHERE   
    x.type = 'P'        
    AND x.number <= DATEDIFF(MONTH, @StartDate, @EndDate)
```

[image]

The result of my query....

What I want is that from february to december  it'll have a year of 2016 and from january to march it'll have a 2017 year..... based on the parameter that I've given..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT YEAR(y.dt) AS Year,
       MONTH(y.dt) AS Month,
       DATENAME(MONTH, y.dt) AS MonthName
FROM    master.dbo.spt_values x
CROSS APPLY (SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, x.number, @StartDate)) AS y(dt)
WHERE   x.type = 'P'        
AND     x.number <= DATEDIFF(MONTH, @StartDate, @EndDate)
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a5450/3)